# Chosen.js - jQuery on Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I am using chosen.js (http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) and I have a select box that I want to manipulate the page based on the chosen option. I see in their docs they have an example on how to do this. The only problem is that when I run this script.

```
$("#form_field").chosen().change(function() {
    console.log('hit');
});
```

It runs on first change. Then it dies and it never runs again.

I also tried adding a '.bind()' but that didn't work either.

```
$("#form_field").bind('change',function() {});
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with what you have.. It works perfectly fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/LUYcA/1/

Comment: Strange. I wonder whats breaking on my page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the problem was that my options had the same name for each. So it was not registering the change. I need some sleep loosing my mind...

Thanks for your help Lucuma!